# Documenting a Side Effect in a Function Using reST Style Docstrings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, side-effects, code-documentation

I've been using reST style docstrings for a while, but I was browsing through [the sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#python-signatures) again to refresh my memory and realized that I'm not quite sure if there's a "standardized" way to document the side effects of a function. For instance, if we have this stripped-down example function:

```
def HandleMsgFromClient(my_list, my_int):
    '''
    Called when a msg is received from the client
    :param my_list: a list holding some info
    :param my_int: the int received from the client
    '''
    if my_int > 0:
        my_list.append(':)')
    elif my_int < 0:
        my_list.append(':(')
    else:
        my_list.append(':/')
```

Should the side effect of adding something to `my_list` be included in the summary line? In the expanded explanation on the next line? Maybe in a `:meta:` field? Is it possible to highlight the side effect in the same way that we can highlight a parameter, return value, or their types? What's considered best practice to document the side effects of a function in this style?